# What function will take two numbers between 0 and 1, and conditionally invert one based on the other?

Tags: functions

I'm not even sure how to ask this question, so if anyone has a better title, feel free to edit it.

I'm trying to come up with a function $f(c, h)$ where $0 \le c \le 1$ and $0 \le h \le 1$ and where $c$ is the amount by which $h$ will be inverted when $f$ is evaluated.

For example, when $c = 0$, $f = h$. However, when $c = 1$, $f = 1 - h$. Whenever $c = .5$ or $h = .5$, $f = .5$. If $h$ is kept constant, $f$ should equal $h$ when $c = 0$, but linearly become closer to $1 - h$ as $c$ approaches $1$

I tried $f(c, h) = c - h$ first, but that led to $f$ being $-h$ when $c = 0$. Then I tried $(((1 - c) * h) + 1) - h$, but that gave me $f = 1$ when $c = 0$.

**what equation will do this?**

Comment: Please define "the amount by which h will be inverted when f is evaluated".

Comment: @Did I hope this helps. I added "If $h$ is kept constant, $f$ should equal $h$ when $c = 0$, but linearly become closer to $1 - h$ as $c$ approaches $1$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does $f(c,h)=0.5+2(c-0.5)(0.5-h)$ work?

Comment: Perfectly! How did you come up with that?

Comment: In other words, $f(c,h)=c+h-2ch$.

Comment: @Did I guess that just depends on whether you'd prefer evaluating constants or variables.

Comment: @Supuhstar:  I started with $f(c,h)=0.5$ whenever $c=0.5$ or $h=0.5$.  That gave the constant and said everything else should have a factor $(c-0.5)(h-0.5)$  The inversion you asked for changed the sign on this.  The factor $2$ comes from scaling so it can get to $0$ or $1$.  It seemed more natural to me to think of $(0.5,0.5)$ as the origin

Comment: @RossMillikan Very nice :)
  Thank you for this

Comment: @Supuhstar Your comment escapes me.

Comment: @Did your version requires about the same number of steps to solve, but looks cleaner and uses $c$ and $h$ twice, whereas Ross's uses them once and is a bit less immediately obvious.

Comment: @Did:  I agree your version is cleaner to evaluate.  I thought mine showed a bit of where it comes from, but I would use yours in practice.

Comment: Ross: since I expressed no preference for one of these two equivalent formulations, your last comment probably ought to be addressed to the OP.